# attribute error: module 'torch_geometric.data' has no attribute 'from_dict'

Tags: pytorch, runtime-error, attributeerror, pytorch-geometric

*RuntimeError: The 'data' object was created by an older version of PyG. If this error occurred while loading an already existing dataset, remove the 'processed/' directory in the dataset's root folder and try again.
*
For this error, I tried [this](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/discussions/7241) because there wasn't 'processed/' directory.

Then, I got an attribute error that *module 'torch_geometric.data' has no attribute 'from_dict'.*

first I reinstall torch_geometric to downgrade the version from 2.3.1 to 1.7.2.

But still there's no 'to_dict' in the module.

I checked torch_geometric/data/data.py and there was from_dict(to_dict) function.

So I think the version of torch_geometric is not a problem.

Is there any other way to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are confusing the module `torch_geometric.data` with the class `torch_geometric.data.Data`. The `Data` class has the attribute `from_dict/to_dict`, but the `data` module does not.